# In a RelativeLayout, why do the following constraints cause an exception?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a RelativeLayout with two views (call them A and B). The following constraints in my code-behind throw the exception "Constraints as specified contain an unsolvable loop."

```
RelativeLayout.SetYConstraint(A,
    Constraint.RelativeToView(B, (layout, view) => view.Height / 2.0));

RelativeLayout.SetXConstraint(B,
    Constraint.RelativeToView(A, (layout, view) => view.Width + 5));
```

I realize that the problem may be due to the cross-referencing of A and B in both constraints. But it doesn't make sense that this is a problem, given that I'm setting X and Y constraints based on Width and Height, which shouldn't depend on the X and Y values.

Answer (score 0):

All the layout parameters of the view are depended on layout process of `RelativeLayout`. When lay-outing children of the `Relativelayout`, they won't check for specific case of constraints is depended. Instead of that they check for view which is related to which view. Due to cross referencing between the views, your are getting the exception they throw internally for unsolved children.

My suggestion is according their current `RelativeLayout` architecture what your are trying to achieve is not possible.